# CLion - getline crashes on EOF when not in debug mode

Tags: c++, windows, getline, eof, clion

My program attempts to read from stdin line-by-line until it receives ctrl+d:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::string inputLine;

    // Read from stdin, until you get Ctrl+D
    while(std::getline(std::cin, inputLine)) {
       //Do some work...

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, everything works, until the user sends ctrl+D.
When the user enters ctrl+d, the program crashes: I get the Windows error that my process has crashed, and CLion gives me this error message:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

When I run my code in debug mode this doesn't happen! It only happens when I run using CLion's Run button.

I guess I should also note that CLion is configured to send EOF on ctrl+D, even though I am on Windows.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without a [mcve]

Comment: I improved my example, it still happens, even in this minimal code!

Comment: Your "minimal code" will not compile.

Comment: Ctrl-Z is eof on Windows.  The code you posted works fine for me, compiled with VS2015.

Comment: Could your antivirus be causing this? I know that have been many reports of aVast preventing c++ code from working when the sandbox mode was enabled.